# Using Stencil components with Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, web-component, stenciljs

In the Stencil docs section on framework integration with Vue it states the following:

> In order to use the custom element library within the Vue app, the
> application must be modified to define the custom elements and to
> inform the Vue compiler which elements to ignore during compilation.

According to the same page this can be achieved by modifying the config of your Vue instance like this:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/test-\w*/];
```

This relates to Vue 2 however. With Vue 3 (which Ionic Vue uses) you have to use isCustomElement as stated here.

Regretably, I can’t for the life of me get Vue and Stencil to play nice. I have tried setting the config like this:

```
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = tag => /gc-\w*/.test(tag)
```

This causes Vue throw the following warning in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: The `compilerOptions` config option is only respected when using a build of Vue.js that includes the runtime compiler (aka "full build"). Since you are using the runtime-only build, `compilerOptions` must be passed to `@vue/compiler-dom` in the build setup instead.
- For vue-loader: pass it via vue-loader's `compilerOptions` loader option.
- For vue-cli: see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader
- For vite: pass it via @vitejs/plugin-vue options. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/p
```

However, I have no idea how to implement any of the above suggestions using Ionic Vue. I have been messing around with `chainWebpack` in `config.vue.js` but without success so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Vue but here's how I did it:

Add the following to your `./vue.config.js` (or create it if it doesn't exist):

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
  // ignore Stencil web components
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.compilerOptions = {
          ...options.compilerOptions,
          isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('test-')
        }
        return options
      })
  },
}
```

This will instruct Vue to ignore the `test-*` components. Source: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#skipping-component-resolution

Next, load the components in `./src/main.ts`.

Import the Stencil project:

```js
import { applyPolyfills, defineCustomElements } from 'test-components/loader';
```

Then replace `createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')` with:

```js
const app = createApp(App).use(router);

// Bind the custom elements to the window object
applyPolyfills().then(() => {
    defineCustomElements();
});

app.mount('#app')
```

Source: https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue

Comment: can not listen custom event in vue3.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if anyone is using vite2+, just edit the vite.config.js accordingly:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('test-') // ✅ Here
      }
    }
  }) ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```